# access objective-c variable in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, variables

Hi guys I  have two view controllers in my storyboard, a tableViewController and a Normal ViewController. A button in the tableViewController(Not in a cell) segues to the second view. However the tableViewController has an objective-c class which I didn't write by myself.

```
// When data is comming, this will be called
- (void)bleDidReceiveData:(unsigned char *)data length:(int)length {
    NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:length];
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"received data: %@", s);   
}
```

I want to access a "s" from the second view controller which is in swift.

Example:

```
var data : NSString = s
```

Comment: You simply dont. `s` is a local variable in that method, no matter what language, you cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

The way the OC method is written, `s` only exists inside that method.  If you want to get it from code in a different class, it needs to be publicly accessible.

The simplest way is to change from using a local variable to using a property for storing the string.

Comment: Can you please show me how I can do in an example code?I really need it

Comment: What part do you not understand?  Do you know what a property is?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it based on my understanding.

On Objective-C class .h (header)

```
@class yourObjectiveCClass
@interface yourObjectiveCClass {
NSString *s;
}
@property (nonatomic, nullable) NSString *s;
@end
```

An then, on the Objective-C class .m

```
@interface yourObjectiveCClass ()
...
@end

@implementation yourObjectiveCClass
@synthesize *s;
@end
```

Now you can access string s from the Swift file.